# vis.js timeline vertical scrollbar jumps

Tags: vis.js

Im using vis.js timeline.
I'd like to use the vertical scrollbar.
Unfortunately, ths scrollbar is jumping around while using.
Has someone solved this problem?

Thanks for help in advance.

greats roman

**Update:**

You can see the example of the vis.js page. 
There you can see the Problem as well:
http://visjs.org/examples/timeline/other/verticalScroll.html

Futher i have tried a Workaround from following Git post: 
https://github.com/alaarmann/vis/commit/1456cdee2f16938b4dd157406b182cd758c7645vBut it didn't helps.

If you like i can post as well some code of me.

Comment: Can you please share a live example or at least your code itself?

Comment: What did you tried to fix this problem so far?

Comment: @Aniko Litvanyi, i did update the question

Comment: @Xvolks, i did update the question